# DOS Batch file - Copy file based on filename elements

Tags: variables, batch-file, dos, filenames

I need to sort alot of files based on their filename. I would like to use a batch file to do it. I do know what I want but I am not sure of the correct syntax.

Example of filenames I work with: (They are all in the same directory originally)

```
2012_W34_Sales_Store001.pdf  
2012_W34_Sales_Store002.pdf  
2012_W34_Sales_Store003.pdf  

2012_November_Sales_Store001.pdf  
2012_November_Sales_Store002.pdf  
2012_November_Sales_Store003.pdf
```

I would like to extract the information that are located between the "_" signs and put them into a different variable each time. The lenght of the informations contained between the _ signs will be different everytime.

```
Example:
var1="2012"
var2="W34" (or November)
var3="Sales"
var4="001"
```

If I am able to do this, I could then copy the files to the appropriate directory using

```
move %var1%_%var2%_%var3%_%var4%.pdf z:\%var3%\%var4%\%var1%\%var2%
```

It would need to loop because I have Store001 to Store050.
Also, there are not only Sales report, many others are available.

I hope I am clear.

Please help me realize this batchfile!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will make sure that it only attempts to move files that meet the pattern part1_part2_part3_part4.pdf

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=_ delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b *^|findstr /ix "[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*[.]pdf'
) do for /f "eol=_ tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%A in ("%%F") do (
  move "%%F" "z:\%%C\%%D\%%A\%%B"
)
```

If needed, you could add `md "z:\%%C\%%D\%%A\%%B" 2>nul` before the MOVE in case the folders might not exist yet.

Comment: You rock! THank you so much Dbenham

Comment: How would I do if I want to add a condition saying:

If %%C = "Some string" and %%B lenght = 3 caracters
set pathname var to something

but if %%C = "same string" and %%B is longer than 3
set pathname var to something else?

Answer (score 0):

This script will move your files based on the values between the underscore to a like wise constructed path.

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do call :handlefile %%f

:handlefile
set pad=z:
for /f  "delims= tokens=1,* " %%a in ("%1") do call :step %%a %%b
rem this MOVES the file, maybe use echo first for testing
move "%fn%" "%pad%"
exit /B

:step
if !%2!==!! EXIT /B
set pad=%pad%\%1
for /f  "delims=_ tokens=1,* " %%a in ("%2") do call :step %%a %%b
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Basically, I want to extract the strings between the "_" and place those into variable. This will let me then move the filename to the directory using the variables.

Comment: My script will functionally do the same without the need of vars.

Comment: Yes but I need to vars to classify my files after wards.